# How to get the content of an Image inside a Rectangle?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I need to get the content of an Image which is surrounded by a Rectangle. I am using emguCV DetectMultiScale function which returns an Array of Rectangle that contains the location or area of detected Image which I need to get the content. Thanks!

```
results = FindPeople.Find(frameImage, tryUseCuda, tryuseOpenCL, out processingTime, out peopleCount);
foreach (Rectangle rect in results)
{
    CvInvoke.Rectangle(frameImage, rect, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar);
    //Get content of the Rectangle here, frameImage = image
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ROI.

```
CvInvoke.Rectangle(frameImage, rect, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar);
frameImage.ROI = rect; // Will cut your original image down to your rect
```

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to make an Array of frameImage? Cause it will return many Rectangle depending on how many person it detects